# I am trying to make a reverse URL call but getting NOreverse match found

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

I am trying to use reverse URL to call a URL in an app(music) in django, but not able to. Below is my code

```
My main_web_app URL file

    from django.conf.urls import url, include
    from django.contrib import admin


    urlpatterns = [

        url(r'^login$/', include('login.urls')),
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^music/', include('Music.urls'), name='indexView')

    ]
```

My music/URL file

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

    app_name = 'music'

    urlpatterns = [
        # /music/
        url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='indexView'),
        # /music/852
        url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detailsView'),
        # /music/add
        url(r'^add/$', views.AddAlbum.as_view(), name='addView')
    ]
```

My View file

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.views import generic
    from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
    from .models import Album


    class IndexView(generic.ListView):
        template_name = 'Music/index.html'
        context_object_name = 'Album_List'

        def get_queryset(self):
            return Album.objects.all()


    class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
        template_name = 'Music/details.html'
        model = Album


    class AddAlbum(CreateView):
        model = Album
        fields = ['Album_name', 'Artist', 'Genere', 'Album_logo']
```

My Template file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
        {% for album in Album_List %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'music:detialView' %}">{{ album.Album_name }}
             </a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <a href="{% url 'music:addView' %}" > Add Album</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The error coming up is

```
Error during template rendering

In template C:\Users\Varun\Desktop\newsite\Music\templates\Music\index.html, error at line 10
Reverse for 'detailView' not found. 'detailView' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
1   <!DOCTYPE html>
2   <html lang="en">
3   <head>
4       <meta charset="UTF-8">
5       <title>Title</title>
6   </head>
7   <body>
8       <ul>
9       {% for album in Album_List %}
10          <li><a href="{% url 'music:detailView' %}">{{ album.Album_name }}</a></li>
11      {% endfor %}
12      </ul>
13      <a href="{% url 'music:addView' %}" > Add Album</a>
14  </body>
15  </html>
```

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong??
The structure of my application is 
website(main web app) ==> Music(contains 1 model(Album))

Comment: Did the below answer helped you to resolve your issue? If yes, please mark it as accepted. It's a good practice in StackOverflow ;)

Comment: it did help me, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo here. Change your `urls.py` to:

```
url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detailView'),
```

Note the extra `s` inside `detailsView`.

Comment: Didn't notice that. Thanks a lot.  :)